# Adapter Threadpool Error with Jboss

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

I am trying to profile my application with VisualVM.When I add parameters for remoteJMX connection,I am getting the below error.
I am using remote JMX with authentication.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating MBeanProxy: jboss.jca:service=AdapterThreadPool

            at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.init(MBeanProxyExt.java:415)

            at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.<init>(MBeanProxyExt.java:99)

            at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.create(MBeanProxyExt.java:394)

            at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.create(MBeanProxyExt.java:349)

            at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.create(MBeanProxyExt.java:324)

            at com.pscufs.datagateway.base.assist.WorkflowBatchManager.<init>(Unknown Source)

            at com.pscufs.datagateway.DataGatewayRequest.execute(Unknown Source)

            at com.pscufs.host.properties.LocalProperties.getNonCAPProperties(Unknown Source)

            at com.pscufs.host.properties.LocalProperties.getAccountPropertiesFdrCard(Unknown Source)

            at com.pscufs.host.properties.LocalProperties.getAccountProperties(Unknown Source)

            at com.pscufs.enterprise.service.ejb3.session.propertycache.PropertyCacheBean.getPropValuesFromLocal(PropertyCacheBean.java:713)

            ... 77 more
```

Caused by: javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: jboss.jca:service=AdapterThreadPool

```
            at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1094)

            at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBeanInfo(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1372)

            at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getMBeanInfo(JmxMBeanServer.java:880)

            at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.init(MBeanProxyExt.java:407)

            ... 87 more
```

Please Help!

Cheers,
Dwarak

Answer (score 0):

Methinks by enabling jmx authentication you are causing  the instantiation and registration of your mbean instances to fail as the server starts. To be frank I'm not sure that the JBoss container supports being started with this JVM argument. If it works for you and your behind a firewall it might just be better to set jmx authentication to false.